# handle touch inside FragmentActivity

Tags: android, touch, android-fragmentactivity

I have implemented a swipe view using ViewPager layout for a FragmentActivity. That FragmentActivity create a new FregmentPagerAdapter that manage four Fragment class. 
I need to intercept a single touch (whatever Fragment is currently focused) to perform an operation. 
I've try to override onTouchEvent inside my FragmentActivity class, but it doesn't work (maybe because FragmentActivity it's only a container and all view is occupy by a Fragment).
How can i do? 
The operation to perform it's independend from wich fragment it's current shown.

Comment: Could you verify if I understood the problem correctly - no matter in what state your application is and no matter where the user touches the screen you want to invoke the same method? I'll provide the code after I'm sure it is what you're looking for.

Comment: Correct, but just a notification for you. I was wrong with description of my problem. FragmentActivity doesn't use ViewGroup layout, but a ViewPager with PagerTabStrip for show also title of current page.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my main is that you create your own View class implementing OnTouchListener, for example:

```
public class TouchMeView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
  public TouchMeView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
  }
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    //IMPLEMENT YOUR ACTION WITHIN THIS METHOD
    return true;
  }
}
```

Take note that I didn't test this code, hopefully you can modify it on your own.

EDIT: Forgot to add - you should attach an instance of this class to your layout in the onCreate(...) method of your FragmentActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//...
paintView = new PaintView(this);
addContentView(paintView, null);
paintView.requestFocus();
}
```